# Why is Line profiler showing only partial results?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, profiling, line-profiler

My line profiler `%lprun -f` works but **does not show the line contents** but only the numbers. So it is useless for me. It shows some directory problem as below.

```
Timer unit: 1e-07 s

Total time: 0.962042 s

Could not find file C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20788\3519952779.py
Are you sure you are running this program from the same directory
that you ran the profiler from?
Continuing without the function's contents.

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           
     2         1         24.0     24.0      0.0  
     3         6        211.0     35.2      0.0
```

And when I run `%lprun?` i see it's directory is `c:\users\my name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\line_profiler\ipython_extension.py`

**What is the solution here?**

**Things I tried but failed:** **1.** Re-installing line_profiler in the same directory as my code.
**2.** Trying to copy-paste the ipython_extension.py inside my code directory but couldn't locate any AppData folder
**3.** Create a .py file of my code and then re-run the program